# Switch keyboard layouts by combination with caps lock

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I have two keyboard layouts. Is it possible to switch to the first layout by pressing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and switch to the second one by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>?

Comment: What are your two layouts??  If it is one latin and one non-latin, then caps lock on its own can switch between them if you check a box in preferences.

Comment: @TomGewecke yep, I'm using that checkbox. It's better than nothing but still not ideal

Comment: Look at.  https://github.com/utatti/kawa

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it doesn't work with combinations which including `Caps Lock` :(